# A Struct is codable, it means all of it's properties are codable?

Tags: swift, codable

As i understand, if a struct is codable, all properties of the struct are codable.
I tried to encode an object of type PKDrawing (it's a struct in PencilKit), the type is codable, so there are no problem:

```
PKDrawing : Codable
```

And then i tried to encode a property of this object in type PKStroke

```
let drawing1JSON = try? JSONEncoder().encode(stroke)
```

but there are an error "PKStroke need to conform to Encodable"

Do i have misunderstood?
and there a a way that i can encode PKStroke without implement codable manualy?

Comment: Does `PKDrawing` implement its own CodingKeys enum?

Comment: As i see in PencilKit file, there are no CodingKeys enum. 
The PencilKit file has 542 lines of code. There are a way to see more code what under the hood is?

Comment: @QuốcHuyNguyễn CodingKeys are private

Comment: That's not true, but if all properties of a struct are codable, the compiler can synthesise a `Codable` implementation for that struct. Maybe you got that mixed up.

Comment: I haven't used PencilKit before, but the fact that `PKDrawing` is `Codable` while `PKStroke` isn't, is a strong indication that Apple wants you to encode the entire `PKDrawing`, rather than just its strokes.

Comment: @Leo Dabus what happens when CodingKeys are private? We can't read the output file? i just ask that because the output JSON of me is a String of nonsense characters

Comment: @Sweeper so if all properties of struct are codable -> the struct is codable. But a struct is codable doesn't mean all of it's properties are codable?

Comment: @QuốcHuyNguyễn The second part, yep. But the first part is not exactly correct. If all properties of struct are codable **and you conform it to `Codable`** -> the struct is codable. All properties being codable merely allows the compiler to auto-generate a `Codable` implementation, without you having to write all the boilerplate code.

Comment: @Sweeper in case i want to store the PKStroke on Database for collaboration. It make more sense if i only upload new stroke to server instead of upload the whole drawing, right?
There are a way to make PKStroke encodable, even manualy or Apple prevents us to do that?

Comment: @QuốcHuyNguyễn where did you get that `PKStroke` is a property of `PKDrawing`?

Comment: rommex extension PKDrawing {
    public init<S>(strokes: S) where S : Sequence, S.Element == PKStroke
    public var strokes: [PKStroke]

Comment: @QuốcHuyNguyễn yes, you are right, but if you follow the list of extensions for PKDrawing you wil find: `extension PKDrawing : Codable { ...}` -- which means PKDrawing implements a special `encode()` method to comply to `Codable` protocol. Which means PKStroke doesn't have to be automatically compliant.